# iPhone unavailable when trying to run watch app from Xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios9, xcode7, watchos-2

I'm running watch OS 2 (beta 2) and iOS 9 (beta 3) and can't run my watch app because Xcode tells me that the iPhone is unavailable.

I'm guessing this might be a problem with watch OS 2, but if not has anyone got any ideas for how to fix the problem?

I'm running the app from Xcode 7. It deploys fine when running just the iPhone section on it's own but not when I want to run the watch app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you upgrade your iOS/watchOS/Xcode versions up to beta 5? I think it's the first step you have to do.